# Do any of the Puranas praise Advaita?

Tags: puranas, advaita, reference-request

The Puranas are very dualistic in nature, so do any of them praise Advaita Vedanta? And if they do praise Advaita please put up the verses in which Advaita is being praised.

Note: I only want praising not talking or saying that it's an evil philosophy or wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily praise Advaita, but it says that followers of that Yoga will be rewarded with bliss, be freed from the burdens of life, etc. This is a line from the Garuda Purana ([Dhanvantari Samhita- Chapter 246](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122726.html)):

> There are two kinds of Yogas, viz., the Advaita Yoga and the Sankhya Yoga, the absolute concentration of the mind being the essential factor in both these forms. **Practisers of the Advaita Yoga become free from the shackles of existence.** Past, present and future acts are destroyed through knowledge. **He, who hews down the tree of existence with the axe of right discrimination and takes an ablution in the sacred pool of knowledge and apathy, comes by the bliss of Vishnu**.

It's the only Puranic line I could find that explicitly commends Advaita and tells us that it's a good practice.

That said, there's [another set of verses](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-2/d/doc63657.html) from the Garuda Purana that explain: dual/non-dual is not the point, the point is understanding the collectiveness of the universe.

> 89. The word from the Teacher gives liberation; all learning is masquerade. Among thousands of woods the Sañjīvana is best.
> 90. **The non-dual, verily declared auspicious**, is beyond efforts of action, and to be obtained by the word of the Teacher, not by the study of tens of millions of texts.
> 91. Knowledge is said to be of two kinds: study and discrimination. The study is of Śabda Brāhmaṇ; Para Brahmaṇ is reached by discrimination.
> 92. **Some prefer the Non-dual; other prefer the Dual but they do not understand the One Reality, beyond the Dual and Non-dual.**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many verses in Puranas like Bhagavata which praise Advaita.

> The aim of life is inquiry into the Truth, and not the
> desire for enjoyment in heaven by performing religious rites,**Those who
> possess the knowledge of the Truth, call the knowledge of non-duality
> as the Truth,It is called Brahman, the Highest Self.**(SB 1.2.10-11)
>
> Oh Infinite Lord ! **Righteous people really seek you within
> the body (which is composed of matter and the spirit),by discarding
> that which is ‘Not-that’ (non-self).** Can pious men of accurate
> judgement arrive at that correct conclusion, **that the rope lying near
> (which was mistaken fora serpent) is certainly a rope, unless they
> have negated the wrong superimposition of a serpent over that rope
> (through ignorance)**.(SB 10.14.28 )
>
> Its main theme is **quintessence of all Upanishads which is
> characterised by complete oneness identity between Absolute Brahman
> and Atman** .It is one without a second.And its only object is to
> secure moksha.(SB 12.13.12 )
>
> **"I am Brahman. I'm the supreme abode. Brahman, the highest goal, is I
> myself" having realized this and absorbing yourself in the self
> (supreme self)**, which is beyond the limits, you will see neither
> Takshaka snake nor your body **nor the world as being distinct and
> different from your own Atman.**(SB 12.5.11-12)

Comment: Welcome back :)

Comment: Hello bro @Rickross : )

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are Puranas that praise Advaita.

> He therefore does not comprehend that his own Atman is in reality the
> imperishable Brahman. (What he has then) is the erroneous notion of
> the Atman in what is the non-Atman. Hence it is misery.

**Kurma Purana II.2.20**

> All defects such as passion, hatred etc., are brought about due to
> wrong notions. Its greatest defect is performance of actions
> meritorious or otherwise. This is the state.

**Kurma Purana II.2.21**

> It is due to that cause that everyone is invested with different kinds
> of physical bodies. The soul, however, lies concealed within, yet it
> is, everywhere, eternal and free from blemishes.

**Kurma Purana II.2.22**

> It stands single by his maya power and not by its nature. Hence the
> sages say that **non-dualism is the ultimate truth**.

**Kurma Purana II.2.23**

Comment: So there really isn't that many Puranas praising Advaita?

Comment: Srimad Bhagavata Purana acknowledges Jnana marga but praises devotion. "Dharma is what goes to generate devotion to Me; Jnana is the perception of the one Atman pervading all;...." Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.19.27.  I have read only a few Puranas and don't know the number of Puranas praising Advaita.

Answer (score 2):

There are many Puranas, including the Bhagavata, that explicitly describe the Advaita sadhana and the Advaitic goal.  Here are some, of the countless, references:

https://adbhutam.files.wordpress.com/2020/12/garuda-pu.advaita-kannada.pdf     This pdf is a condensation of 5 chapters of Garuda Purana on Advaita.  This file is in Kannada though the verses cited are in Devanagari, original.

https://adbhutam.files.wordpress.com/2020/11/vedanta-garuda-puranam-1.pdf    This is from Garuda Purana, two chapters, in English with the Mahavakya 'Aham Brahma Asmi'.

https://wordpress.com/posts/adbhutam.wordpress.com?s=Advaita
This page gives links along with titles to a very large number of Purana references for Advaitic concepts very clearly laid out, with no ambiguity whatsoever.

There are a number of Advaitic tenets in the Pancharatra Literature too that have been sampled.